# Combinations adding to zero

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

Given five sorted lists: List1, List2, List3, List4, List5 with length n each. if any 5 (int) numbers (1 from each list), sum up to zero return true. My goal is to ensure that the algorithm is O(n). Off the top of my head, I can think of creating either a hash map with sum
of 5 linked lists or evaluating the 5 lists such that [o(n*n*n*n*n)]. I am lookign for ways to optimize or reduce the complexity, and I'm stuck.

My code in Python:

```
def getIndicesFromFiveArrays(List1,List2,List3,List4,List5,t):
    a,b,c,d,e=0,0,0,0,0
    while(List1[a]+List2[b]+List3[c]+List4[d]+List5[e]!=t):
        b=b+1
        if b==len(List2):
            return (-1,-1)
        if List1[a]+List2[b]+List3[c]+List4[d]+List5[e]<t:
            a=a+1
            b=b-1
        c=c-1
        d=d-1
        e=e-1
            if a==len(List1):
                return (-1,-1)
    return (a,b,c,d,e)
```

EDIT 1: this is not homework by the way, you may check my other questions and verify for yourself. thanks..

Comment: Are these lists holding floats or just ints?

Comment: these lists contain ints

Comment: giving +1 to counteract the negative vote given.

Comment: Where's the linked list here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were 2 lists, you would take a number from list 1 and then look for the negative of that number in list 2. If you replaced list 2 with a set, the overall complexity would be O(n).

If there were 3 lists, you would take a number from list 1 and then one from list 2, with a complexity of O(n^2). If you replaced list 3 with a set, the overall complexity would be O(n^2).

So I think that the overall complexity for 5 lists/sets can't be reduced below O(n^4).

Comment: The lists are sorted, which allows an O(n) solution which isn't possible in the general case, at least for 2 lists. I'm not sure how to generalize it.

Comment: It's definitely can be reduced below O(n^4).

Answer (score 2):

There's an O(n^3) solution, inspired by MRAB's comment.

First, combine every value from list 1 with every value from list 2 and store it in a set. Call the result set 1and2, it has n^2 values.

Next, combine set 1and2 with list 3. Call the result set 1and2and3, it has n^3 values, and takes n^3 steps to construct.

Next, combine lists 4 and 5. Call the result set 4and5, it has n^2 values.

Finally, check to see if any value in set 4and5 is equal to the inverse of a value in set 1and2and3. This step takes n^2 steps.

This approach uses O(n^3) space and O(n^3) time.

As Karoly Horvath points out, you don't actually need to store set 1and2and3, you could construct it on the fly from set 1and2 during the last step. This approach uses only O(n^2) space, but still requires O(n^3) time. Here's the code:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,10]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,11]
l3 = [1,2,3,4,5,12]
l4 = [1,2,3,4,5,13]
l5 = [1,2,3,4,5,-46]

def test():
    l1_2 = [a + b for a in l1 for b in l2]
    set4_5 = set([a + b for a in l4 for b in l5])
    return any([True for x in l1_2 for y in l3 if -(x + y) in set4_5])

print test()
```

Comment: you can do this with O(n^2) space, it's enough to store 1and2.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: I can see how it's possible to do it in O(n^3), but not O(n^2).